# Hello! Can someone please translate: 'My Little Ghost' to Chinese?

Tags: translation, mandarin, pinyin, spelling

I'm creating a story with this title and the setting I'm supposed to have is in ancient China. It would be helpful if you can show me how it is spelled and if the translated version sounds more like an endearment from an older boy to a younger boy. Thank you!

Comment: 我之小鬼, as far as sounding like an endearment from an older boy to one younger, i don't even think the English form firs that description

Comment: Quote:- "...an endearment from an older boy to a younger boy ".  小鬼" is suitable only if the younger boy, in your story, is "naughty, crafty, mischievous", like, for example, constantly playing pranks.

Answer (score 1):

> My Little Ghost: 我的小鬼:
> Wǒ de xiǎoguǐ

Answer (score 1):

Since your story background is in ancient China, expressions such as 我的小鬼 seems to be inappropriate.
If you're considering making the story in Classical Chinese, the following words may be helpful:

> - **Calling a younger brother:** *When both are young, the older can call the younger by his nickname/infant name; When grown up, the older should call his younger brother by Zi (a certain nickname used to refer to someone respectfully).*
> - **Offensive expressions used for cursing:** 竖子, 小子, etc.

If you still want to use modern Chinese, you can simply use:

> 弟弟, 老弟, 小屁孩 (contemptuous/joking)

I finished this in a hurry so I didn't have time to provide the words' pronunciations. Type those words in Google Translate and you'll get corresponding Pinyins, mostly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

小鬼 is used to refer to little kids.

There is a phrase:

人小鬼大
literally: small person big demon
mischievous (and clever) kid

Maybe you could use:

亲爱的小幽灵
dear little ghostie